# How do i generate a code like this DEL-1234 in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys please i am new to php mysql, i am trying to generate a code like this DEL-12345. So if the person chooses the state Delaware in the form, it generates and stores DEL-23413 in the db on submit. DEL (First 3 letters of the state); - (Hyphen) and then 12345 (5 random numbers)...

please help

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code so we can help you. We rather not like to create your code, we like it to help you with your existing code :)

Comment: i have a code that generates random alphanumeric code :3l82Vkj2R function generatePasswordsUsingNumbers($length){
$numbers='0123456789'; 
$password_characters = str_split($numbers);
$password=''; 

for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){ 
$password.=$password_characters[rand(0,count($password_characters)-1)];
}
return $password;
}

Comment: function generatePasswordsUsingCharactersAndNumbers($passwordLength){
$characters='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 
$password_characters = str_split($characters);
$password=''; 

for($i=0;$i<$passwordLength;$i++){ 
$password.=$password_characters[rand(0,count($password_characters)-1)];
}
return $password;
}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would like to point you in the right direction with the code below.

```
$Area = "Utah";
$Code = strtoupper(substr($Area, 0, 3)) . "-" . (mt_rand(1000,9999));
echo ( $Code );
```

However, note that this code is subject to errors for example:
What if the $Area variable contained a string less than 3 characters?
What if the random value generated is not unique (the theory being you want it to be)

All of this needs to be checked, by you, give it a go - we can help if needed but we wont write the whole code for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very important points to think about...Please one more question what if i have about 30 cities and i want to generate the first 3 letters for each city depending on which city is chosen...

Comment: Assuming you have post data... just have a drop-down box that has each city in it, let's say it's called CitySelection... you could then do: $Area = $_POST['CitySelection']; to obtain what city was selected in POST data from a <Form>

Answer (score -1):

Use `substr()` function to fetch first 3 letters from state, then `mt_rand()` to generate random digit like this:

```
$state = "Delhi";
$code = strtoupper(substr($state, 0, 3)) . '-' . mt_rand(10000, 99999);

// Output "DEL-26845"
```

However you can find another more promising way to improve the **random digit** part to generate unique 5 random digit each time...

Comment: Please one more question what if i have about 30 cities and i want to generate the first 3 letters for each city depending on which city is chosen